# Is there a way to show Quick Links were some of these quick links open in a modal popup

Tags: sharepoint-online, development, spfx, spfx-webparts, modern-experience

I want to add this Quick link inside our SharePoint online:

[image]

Where the HR System & Our People will open links from external system and a SharePoint page. while when the users clicks on Who we are and Our Values to show a popup windows with some text.

Is this possible?

I think the built-in Quick Links Web part does not provide this feature.

But can I build an SPFX or use 3rd part SPFx to do this job?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right about SharePoint out of the box quick links web part does not support this functionality.

You can build similar web part using SPFx for sure.

You can use [Dialog control](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/fluentui#/controls/web/dialog) in Fluent UI to show pop-up & text/buttons on pop-up.

---

**Additional**:

Here are few samples to show the capabilities of SPFx development:

1. [Custom Links](https://github.com/pnp/sp-dev-fx-webparts/tree/main/samples/React-custom-links)
2. [Links Web Part](https://github.com/pnp/sp-dev-fx-webparts/tree/main/samples/React-links)

Comment: thanks for the reply, and the link.. but can you provide more usful reply (if you can) on how i can create such a SPFx? thanks

Comment: Check [this documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/web-parts/get-started/build-a-hello-world-web-part) for creating basic SPFx web part. Once you create a basic web part, you have to add the npm packages & functionalities specific to your requirements (to show the dialog >> there are multiple ways, [react components](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-dialog), Fluent UI, basic [HTML/CSS](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_modals.asp), etc >> you have to decide this as per your requirements/design).

Comment: If you are expecting ready made web part or fully developed code, it is not feasible to provide such information/code in an answer on the forum. Best way you can do is, take the code from links I provided in my answer & add the dialog/popup functionality on your own.

Comment: Few examples to show dialog in SPFx: [MS Docs example in SPFx extensions](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/extensions/guidance/using-custom-dialogs-with-spfx), [How To Use Dialog Control Of Fluent UI In SPFx](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/how-to-use-dialog-control-of-fluent-ui-in-spfx/), [using react-modal library](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/2b1cccc1-5fda-4fd1-b1ae-0438a96672f8/display-pop-up-or-dialog-box-onclick-of-button-in-react-js-spfx-webpart-in-sharepoint-online?forum=sharepointdevelopment)